# How to traverse within a class that has list of the same as property?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class like this

```
 public class FilterConditionDto
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool Parent { get; set; }

    public string[] Value { get; set; }

    public string Column { get; set; }

    public string DataType { get; set; }

    public string Operator { get; set; }

    public List<FilterConditionDto> nodes { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a loop that traverse all elements and the inner list elements of the inner list, please note that the elements in the list can also contain a list inside.

Comment: What do you want to do while traversing?

Comment: Obvious as this may sound, I suggest you initialize `nodes` to an empty list in the constructor and make its setter `private`, so that you can just loop without having to check the collection against `null`.

Comment: Why would you create unused objects? @s.m. In some cases that might have quite some memory impact.

Comment: @PatrickHofman because 1) a null collection goes horribly against the principle of least surprise (how many times have you consumed a .NET class and found that a hypothetical `Children` collection was `null`?) and 2) after appropriate profiling has clearly shown that a few empty lists are indeed causing huge memory consumption, making the initialization lazy would be trivially simple (also because of the private setter). Sprinkling the code with null checks because you *think* that a bunch of empty collections *could* be a problem means making it more complex than it really needs to be.

Comment: Then option 2 is the only right solution.

Comment: @PatrickHofman again, until you've measured it's hard to tell which one is "the only right solution". Somehow I sense OP could hit totally unrelated performance issues way before those empty lists begin to look even remotely like a problem. But yes, you can declare a backing field and set it if it's null. Better do it precisely that way, though, because if you did it with `Lazy<T>` you would be creating just as many "unused objects" anyway (and arguably heavier ones at that, since a lambda is also involved in that case). I prefer to just keep it simple unless additional complexity is granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion to do what you want:

```
private void Filter(FilterConditionDto dto)
{
    if (dto != null)
    {
        // do something with dto

        if (dto.nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (FilterConditionDto subDto in dto.nodes)
            {
                Filter(subDto); // <-- here you call the method recursively
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for circular references. You would have to keep track of what FilterConditionDto you've traversed

Comment: That only applies when your filters have m:n relations, not 1:n.

Comment: Stackoverflow on this one 
var f = new FilterConditionDto();
f.nodes = new List<FilterConditionDto>() {f};
Filter(f);

Comment: The return of each iteration would be a string, and I would like to append the results into a big string.

Comment: Then use a `StringBuilder` and pass that along in every recursive call.

Comment: So u r saying that the return type of my function should be string and I can append using string builder?

Comment: I would pass in a `ref StringBuilder sb`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion

```
public void Traverse(List<FilterConditionDto> models)
{
    foreach(var item in models)
    {
      if(item.nodes.Count > 0)
      {
          Traverse(item.nodes)
      }
    }
}
```